# Как определить окончание слова?

Tags: состав-слова

Требуется автоматически определить окончание слова (программно). Но не знаю, на самом деле, как это последовательно делается даже человеком.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Давайте спросим попугая" (с)
В смысле программиста.

Для точного решения нужен словарь в виде базы данных с указанием для каждого слова длины основы (приставка+корень+суффикс). Но и в этом случае 100% гарантированного автоматического решения не будет, поскольку теоретически могут быть слова, подпадающие (при одинаковом начертании) под разные парадигмы (например, глагола и существительного) и имеющие при этом разные окончания. У меня такого словаря нет, найдёте ли в свободном доступе — сомнительно.

Если особой точности не нужно, то используют т. н. "Стеммер Портера" — алгоритм стемминга (нахождения основы слова для заданного исходного слова). [Вот](https://eigenein.xyz/snowball/) один из примеров.

Answer (score 2):

Как определить  - пожалуйста, а программно - я пас, пусть программисты отвечают.

Окончание - это изменяемая часть слова. Таким образом, у неизменяемых частей речи его нет. Отсутствуют они у наречий, деепричастий, сравнительной степени.

Если вы испытываете затруднения при выявлении окончания, изменяйте форму слова и выявляйте ту часть, которая изменяется. Это и будет окончание. Например, вам нужно выделить окончание у слова "стол". Попробуйте изменить его форму: "стола", "столу", "столом" и т.д. Обратите внимание, что изменение происходит сразу после корня. Можно сделать вывод, что окончанием у слова "стол" нулевое.

Нулевые окончания - это такие части слова, которые не выражены звуками. Как правило, они встречаются у существительных в форме именительного падежа мужского рода второго склонения или в третьем склонении.

Нужно  различать окончания глаголов повелительного и изъявительного наклонений. Звучание в них может быть одинаковым, а вот части слова разными. Обратите внимание на глагол "крикните". Он употребляется в повелительном наклонении. Измените форму и сможете увидеть, что в слове « крикни»  на конце –И , в слове «крикните» - ИТЕ . Меняется только –ТЕ, значит, в глаголе "крикните" – окончание "те".,  а –И – суффикс.

В предложении "Когда крикнете, сообщите"  глагол "крикнете" употреблен в изъявительном наклонении. Если измените форму слова (крикнем, крикнешь), то увидите, что окончанием будет "ете".(крикн – не меняется, основа)

Вот здесь об окончании подробно: http://licey.net/russian/phonetics/2_9

Comment: Извините дилетанта...  
Почему Вы при спряжении глагола взяли за базу "крикни", а не "крикнуть", т.е. проварьировали всего лишь единственное/множественное число повелительного наклонения и на этом основании "и" записали в суффиксы?

Comment: Я не давала парадигму глагола, я показала разницу морфемного состава глаголов повелительного и изъявительного наклонений.В повелительном наклонении И суффикс(в повелит.наклонении только 2 формы - ед.и множ.число, других форм нет), в изъявит. "Е" входит в окончание -ЕТЕ

Comment: М-да...
А я-то по темноте своей полагал, что корень - "крик", "н" - суффикс, а что поверх того - то окончание (может быть, с частицей).
Век живи...